# How to know current background image name on Trello?

Tags: trello

I want to get the name of my current Trello background so as to share to my colleagues.

I tried to look all around Trello menus but failed to find a way to do so.

So if you know how to get the background name, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Chrome:

- Select the background for your board.
- Press **CTRL+Shift+I** (Inspect)
- Under the Elements tab see the **< body >** tag and copy the last part of the link. (e.g. "photo-1495313637066-a8afb6a68bfe")
- You can share that with your friends to find it. 
  [image]

The background images are from Unsplash, so you can also use the link to download the image or follow the collection of that artist and find the image you need and download.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer thanks to [User552853's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106273/3520).

Solution as attached snapshot and below notes

Open Trello board in Chrome browser

- 1 open Chrome "inspector" aka. hit F11
- 2 click on `body` tab in the DOM
- 3 search for `background-image` in the **Styles** tab
- 4 copy the image filename of the url(...)
- 5 go to Trello change background
- 6 paste the image filename
- 7 you got the image

[image: screen shot]